# How do I set an image url from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am writing an Open University project that requires me to use Cordova to generate an Android app. To do this, I am using a combination of HTML and JavaScript.

My HTML uses

```
<div data-role="page" id="view">
```

etc. to define individual pages within the single HTML file. When the page first runs, it shows a "corporate" logo. After signing in, it shows the personal logo. The url to the logo comes from a database and is held in a JS global variable railroadLogoPath. I have an HTML placeholder Once I move to another page, I can't see how to get the HTML to use the JS to get the url of this logo.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<img class="banner" id = "signedInlogo"  width = "100%">
```

I have a JS function in index.js as follows:

```
function insertLogo(anID) {

document.getElementById("anID").src = railroadLogoPath;
}
```

How do I call this from HTML. I have tried putting it in

```
<script> insertLogo("signedInLogo")</script>
```

but this doesn't work.

I am just starting to understand JS so any help would be appreciated.
David

Comment: change this line `document.getElementById("anID").src = railroadLogoPath;` to `document.getElementById(anID).src = railroadLogoPath;`

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
document.getElementById("anID").src = railroadLogoPath;
```

You're looking for an element by ID with the literal string `"anID"`. You should be using the variable `anID`

```
function insertLogo(anID) {
    document.getElementById(anID).src = railroadLogoPath;
}
```